# how to extract 2 chars after the third occurrence of "_" using regex in R

Tags: r, regex

I wanted to extract some info from file names using regex, from this vector of strings

```
ss <-c("africa_AF_1_20_perc_threshold_in_MOD44B.MRTWEB.A2000065.051.Percent_Tree_Cover.tif_Patch_areas","africa_AF_1_25_perc_threshold_in_MOD44B.MRTWEB.A2000065.051.Percent_Tree_Cover.tif_Patch_areas","africa_AF_1_30_perc_thresholdinMOD44B.MRTWEB.A2000065.051.Percent_Tree_Cover.tif")
```

I want to extract the numbers after the third "_", I tried this

```
gsub("(?:.*?_){3}([^_]+)","\\1",ss)
```

I tested the expression using https://regex101.com/r/6QqHwf/6 and it is correct, the output should be 20, 25, 30 but I obtain

```
[1] "areas"     "areas"     "Cover.tif
```

Comment: In your example expected output should be `20`?

Comment: Yes the expected output should be 20,25,30

Comment: `sub("^(?:[^_]*_){3}([^_]+).*", "\\1", ss)`

Comment: This one also works: `gsub("([^_]*_){3}([[:digit:]]*).*", "\\2", ss)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the caret `^` to make sure you match at the start of the string and also make sure you match the whole string with `.*`at the end of the pattern:

```
ss <-c("africa_AF_1_20_perc_threshold_in_MOD44B.MRTWEB.A2000065.051.Percent_Tree_Cover.tif_Patch_areas","africa_AF_1_25_perc_threshold_in_MOD44B.MRTWEB.A2000065.051.Percent_Tree_Cover.tif_Patch_areas","africa_AF_1_30_perc_thresholdinMOD44B.MRTWEB.A2000065.051.Percent_Tree_Cover.tif")
sub("^(?:[^_]*_){3}([^_]+).*", "\\1", ss)
## => [1] "20" "25" "30"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/B9TikU). Note you do not need `gsub`, since you only want to perform a single search and replace operation, a `sub` will do.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^_]*_){3}` - 3 occurrences of

  - `[^_]*` - zero or more chars other than `_`
  - `_` - an underscore
- `([^_]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `_`
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

The `\1` is the replacement pattern that inserts the value captured in Group 1.